# Pyspark number of unique values in dataframe is different compared with Pandas result

Tags: pandas, dataframe, unique, pyspark

I have  large dataframe with 4 million rows. One of the columns is a variable called "name".

When I check the number of unique values in Pandas by: `df['name].nunique()` I get a different answer than from Pyspark `df.select("name").distinct().show()` (around 1800 in Pandas versus 350 in Pyspark). How can this be? Is this a data partitioning thing?

EDIT: 
The record "name" in the dataframe looks like: name-{number}, for example: name-1, name-2, etc.

In Pandas:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.lstrip('name-').astype(int)
df['name'].nunique() # 1800
```

In Pyspark:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f 
df = df.withColumn("name", f.split(df['name'], '\-')[1].cast("int"))
df.select(f.countDistinct("name")).show()
```

Comment: No, you should not see that. Post as much of your code as you can.

Comment: Can you try this? `df.select(pyspark.sql.functions.countDistinct("name")).show()`. Don't forget to execute `import pyspark` first.

Comment: See my edit. Proposed method gave the same result however

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, it's most likely from non-numeric chars(i.e. SPACE) shown in the `name` column. Pandas will force the type conversion while with Spark, you get *NULL*, see below example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(e,) for e in ['name-1', 'name-22 ', 'name- 3']],['name'])
```

for PySpark:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn("name1", f.split(df['name'], '\-')[1].cast("int")).show()                                            
#+--------+-----+
#|    name|name1|
#+--------+-----+
#|  name-1|    1|
#|name-22 | null|
#| name- 3| null|
#+--------+-----+
```

for Pandas:

```
df.toPandas()['name'].str.lstrip('name-').astype(int)                                                              
#Out[xxx]: 
#0    1
#1   22
#2    3
#Name: name, dtype: int64
```